# What's with the privacy with Captain America?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> There's a scene in which Steve Rogers and Tony Stark are chopping wood. Then, Hawkeye's wife comes and asks Tony to fix the tractor. But it turns out to be Nick Fury near the tractor.

Now, the question is: Why did Nick Fury do this? Wasn't Captain America trustworthy? Couldn't he talk to Tony in front of Steve?

In *Captain America: Winter Soldier* movie, just after his death, Nick Fury trusted Captain America. What happened now?

Comment: I don't think Fury completely trusts anyone, even himself.

Comment: I love that you're cagey about who the question is about behind the spoiler tag, and then name him immediately afterwards outside of the spoiler tag.

Comment: @phantom42: He's credited on the poster. Everyone knows Nick Fury will be in this movie. The spoiler tag helps people who haven't seen it yet avoid being spoiled as to when Fury will show up, which is definitely treated as a surprise in the film.

Comment: @MasonWheeler My point is that reading the *rest* of the question, it's very clear who is talking to Tony and not to Steve - despite the use of a spoiler tag.

Comment: The only real spoiler in the question is just *who* asks Tony to fix the tractor, and that doesn't even need to be in the question aside from wanting to mention who it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fury's focus at that point was to give Tony a pep-talk. He wanted Tony to get back on the saddle & start focusing on how to bring down Ultron. Up until that point Tony was completely engrossed in self-hatred/self-pity.

Rogers & rest of the Avengers were pretty upset with Tony in this aspect. They might not have been so sympathetic when Fury was basically telling Tony something to the tunes of "everybody makes mistakes" & shake it off.

This conversation would not at all be smooth with anybody else there.

Makes sense that Fury would want to have this conversation with just the two of them present.

Comment: +1.  All the Avengers were mad at Tony, and Steve especially.  After all, he *had* just ripped a log in half with his bare hands mere moments before.

Comment: Yeah... Rogers was about an inch away from taking out his anger on Tony... Especially with all that log ripping it feels so.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s possible that Hawkeye’s wife actually did want Tony to fix their tractor, and wasn’t even aware that

> Nick Fury

was in the barn at the time.

I don’t remember the barn scene very well, but I don’t think anything particularly confidential was discussed there. And fairly soon afterwards,

> Fury

is in the kitchen with everyone, merrily talking about everything that’s going on.

So I don’t think there’s actually anything to indicate that Captain America, or anyone else, isn’t trusted.

Comment: You know what... You look like my school maths teacher whom I always hated... He also used to give similar logic.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: he sounds like a smart and handsome guy.

Comment: His first words were something like "Try not to bring it to life", so yeah, I don't think she knew either

Answer (score 2):

To my interpretation, Tony's the type of character who, unless you're in his "inner circle," you sort of have to knock down a couple walls to really get across to him. Though he's grown a bit more comfortable in his own skin, Stark is still a pretty prickly and defensive person. There's an uneasy alliance between him and Steve at the moment in this story, so I think Fury probably thought it'd be easier to talk to Tony w/o Steve around. More a psychological than practical motivation.